# When did Iriden 3 get blown up in the Dark Matter timeline?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark-matter

I'm halfway through season 2 of Dark Matter.  There is constant reference to the main characters blowing up Iriden 3.  I've been trying to find where in season 1 it was revealed that this happened.  Can anyone recall?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to BCdotWEB, I was referred to hints at [a white hole bomb page](http://darkmatter.wikia.com/wiki/White_hole_bomb).  The episodes (season 1, episodes 10 through 12) are listed under "Appearances", under the photo.  I reviewed the episodes and found that Iriden was destroyed in episode 11.